# How do I tell which Python interpreter I'm using?

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.5.2. How can I tell whether it is `CPython` or `IronPython` or `Jython`?

Another question: how can I **use a DLL** developed in VB.NET in my project?

Comment: You should split this into two separate questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you downloaded it as the default thing from python.org, it's CPython. That's the “normal” version of Python, the one you get when you use the command “python”, and the one you'll have unless you specifically went looking for the projects targeting Java/CIL.

And it's CPython because neither of the other projects have reached version number 2.5.2.

> How can i use a dll developed in VB.NET in to my project?

From CPython, using [Python-for-.NET](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/)(*) and clr.AddReference.

(*: actually a bit of a misnomer, as with CPython in control it is more like .NET-for-Python.)

Comment: how to makee python-for-.NET compatible with Python2.5.2?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it already is. Take the ‘python2.5-UCS2’ build from the download.

Answer (score 16):

```
import platform    
platform.python_implementation()
```

The above one provide the type of interpreter you use .

Answer (score 4):

If you are typing "python" to launch it, it is probably CPython. IronPython's executable name is "ipy".

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
print sys.version
```

Comment: sys.version and platform.python_implementation() give answers to two different questions. sys.version gives more or less just a version of a python interpreter, not its implementation. You may see some GCC information at the end of the version line but for unskilled user it barely tells anything. while platform.python_implementation() gives exact answer to the exact question.

Comment: Furthermore, this exactly information appears right after interactive mode have been started:    $ python
    Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
    [GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Well since the first part of your question has been answered, I'll tackle the second part. .NET dll's can be accessed from python in various ways. If you are using ironpython it makes this especially easy, since all .NET languages can interact with eachother fairly seamlessly. In this case you would access your dll from ironpython just as you would any other .NET dll you made with ironpython. If you want to call a native dll you can use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html).